Any way to retrieve app store receipts for auto-renewable subscription other than uploading from the app?
I have an iOS app that offers auto-renewable subscriptions and I'm migrating my client/server system to RevenueCat to fully manage the subscriptions there.
Speaking of migrating to the RevenueCat, there are two ways - server-side migration and client-side migration (Ref). I'm thinking of doing it with the server-side migration since it can cause a data mismatch between Apple <> RevenueCat with the client-side migration that requires users to launch the app.
RevenueCat requires raw app receipts in Server-side migration. However, I have never uploaded receipts and stored them on my server as I've been relying on the App Store Server Notification.

⚠️COMPLETE APPLE BASE64 RECEIPT FILE REQUIRED
RevenueCat requires the raw base64 encoded Apple receipt to import the subscription properly. Partial receipts or the receipt information from the Apple server-to-server notifications are insufficient.

If my understanding is correct, none of the App Store Server APIs provides access to the raw app receipt. it seems that their basic concept is to provide Transactions instead of receipt for better developer experience.
Given that, I'm wondering if there's any way to retrieve our users' receipts without uploading them from our app. I'm guessing there's no way though, I want to confirm that I'm not misunderstanding.
